# Reading nested elements/sequences using dicom leadtools

Tags: c#, dicom

I have a dicom dataset xml dump like this ( source is .dcm file which can be converted to the below xml dump section. I want to parse different element values under the nested sequence. How can i do this using leadtools sdk and dicom dataset objecT ?

```xml
<sequence tag="0024,0032" vr="SQ" card="1" len="128" name="FixationSequence">
<item card="5" len="120">
<sequence tag="0024,0033" vr="SQ" card="1" len="66" name="FixationMonitoringCodeSequence">
<item card="3" len="58">
<element tag="0008,0100" vr="SH" vm="1" len="6" name="CodeValue">111845</element>
<element tag="0008,0102" vr="SH" vm="1" len="4" name="CodingSchemeDesignator">DCM</element>
<element tag="0008,0104" vr="LO" vm="1" len="24" name="CodeMeaning">Macular Fixation Testing</element>
</item>
</sequence>
<element tag="0024,0035" vr="US" vm="1" len="2" name="FixationCheckedQuantity">17</element>
<element tag="0024,0036" vr="US" vm="1" len="2" name="PatientNotProperlyFixatedQuantity">0</element>
<element tag="0024,0039" vr="CS" vm="1" len="4" name="ExcessiveFixationLossesDataFlag">YES</element>
<element tag="0024,0040" vr="CS" vm="1" len="2" name="ExcessiveFixationLosses">NO</element>
</item>
</sequence>
```

Question1 : How to get the value of 'Macular Fixation Testing' for 'CodeMeaning' using the hierarchy of :

```
<sequence tag="0024,0032" vr="SQ" card="1" len="128" name="FixationSequence">
    <item card="5" len="120">
        <sequence name="FixationMonitoringCodeSequence" len="66" vr="SQ" tag="0024,0033" card="1">
                <item len="58" card="3">
                        <element name="CodeMeaning" len="24" vm="1" vr="LO" tag="0008,0104">Macular Fixation Testing</element>
```

Question2 : How do i read the value of '17' for tag name 'FixationCheckedQuantity' using the heirarchy (nesting) of :

```xml
<sequence tag="0024,0032" vr="SQ" card="1" len="128" name="FixationSequence">
    <element tag="0024,0035" vr="US" vm="1" len="2" name="FixationCheckedQuantity">17</element>
```

I want to search using  FixationCheckedQuantity-->FixationSequence-->FixationCheckedQuantity.

How can we get the element values using C# and leadtools sdk  for nested elements/sequences.

Answer (score 0):

You start by finding the sequence using FindFirstElement(). You can then obtain all child elements of the sequence using GetChildElement() followed by a loop that contains GetNextElement().
The following code sample shows this:

```
//ds is a DicomDataSet object that has the data set loaded
DicomElement SeqElement = ds.FindFirstElement(null, DicomTag.FixationMonitoringCodeSequence, false);
if (SeqElement != null)
{
   DicomElement ChildElement = ds.GetChildElement(SeqElement, true);
   while (ChildElement != null)
   {
      string tagName = DicomTagTable.Instance.Find(ChildElement.Tag).Name;
      string elementValue = ds.GetConvertValue(ChildElement);
      Console.WriteLine("element tag: " + tagName);
      Console.WriteLine("element value: " + elementValue);
      ChildElement = ds.GetNextElement(ChildElement, true, true);
   }
}
```

If you can’t get this to work the way you want it, you can send the actual dataset to support@leadtoosl.com and explain what you’re trying to do exactly.